# undefined onPress on TouchableOpacity after assigning value

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have this loop on my react native application:

```
         for(var i = 0; i<sets.length;i++)  {
            console.log('sets[i].setName = '+sets[i].setName);
            arrViews.push(
                 <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={()=> editSetBtn(sets[i].setName, sets[i].questions)}
                    lesQuestions={sets[i].questions} 
                    key={i}>
                     <Text>
                       {sets[i].setName}
                     </Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>);
            }
```

When I run it I do have `sets[i].setName = Set name` in the console, but when I click on  the touchableOpcatity i get this error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sets[i].setName')

createReactClass$argument_0.touchableHandlePress
    TouchableOpacity.js:264:45
touchableHandlePress
    [native code]:0
TouchableMixin._performSideEffectsForTransition
    Touchable.js:880:34
_performSideEffectsForTransition
    [native code]:0
TouchableMixin._receiveSignal
    Touchable.js:779:44
_receiveSignal
    [native code]:0
TouchableMixin.touchableHandleResponderRelease
    Touchable.js:490:24
touchableHandleResponderRelease
    [native code]:0
forEach
    [native code]:0
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Does someone knows why?

**EDIT AND FIX:**
So I changed my loop to this and it worked :

```
            for(var i = 0; i<sets.length;i++){
            console.log('sets[i].setName = '+sets[i].setName);
            let name = sets[i].setName;
            let questions = sets[i].questions;
            arrViews.push(<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> editSetBtn(name, questions)} lesQuestions={sets[i].questions} key={i}><Text>{sets[i].setName}</Text></TouchableOpacity>);
        }
```

But I still need to know why did this happened?

Comment: Please share your editSetBtn function

Comment: here it is :
    function editSetBtn(setName, questions){
        setSetInfos([setName, questions]);
        setModalMode('edit');
        setSetsModalVisible(true);        
    }
setModalMode and setSetsModalVisible aur useState functions..
If you need something else let me know

Comment: you can also just change `var i = 0` to `let i = 0` to make it work. otherwise when you click it's going to check for `i`'s value which got incremented throughout your loop. if you want to try it out, change `onPress` to `onPress={()=> console.log(i)}`

Comment: Oh ok thank you @MattAft